# Using SDL2_gfx issues using C++

Tags: c++, sdl

When I use SDL2_gfx with the common.c /common.h files that are included with it, and then use the cpp instead of c extension using VS201X, I get the LNK2019: unresolved external symbol  _SDL_main

What that means is if I change the file containing main to test.c, it compiles. When I change it back to text.cpp it fails to compile.
I think that indicates that it only works as C, and not C++.

Below is the code I copied from SDL2_gfxPrimitives.c (Spaces added so they would show up):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "common.h"

#include "SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h"

static CommonState *state;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
/* Initialize test framework */
state = CommonCreateState(argv, SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

return 1;
}
```

I need to use the library in C++ but it seems I don't know enough to figure out how. Any help would be appreciated, I've spent two days attempting to figure this out.

Comment: Can you specify exactly which version of Visual Studio you're using? Also - are you adding the path to the SDL2.lib to your test project? Do you have the SDL2.dll referenced in your test project as well? How different is your test project from the one that comes with a fresh download?

Comment: I did a fresh download - and used your test.cpp in the test project. I had to comment out the line `state = CommonCreateState(argv, SDL_INIT_VIDEO);` as that was giving me unresolved external errors and then it compiled fine. Your compile error may be something to do with not having a reference to the SDL2.dll or .lib files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a little bit of a gotcha for SDL.

What it does is `#define main SDL_main`

This renames `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` into `int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

In order to use it, SDL wants an unmangled `SDL_main` to link against, and because you simply renamed the `test.c` -> `test.cpp`, you didn't add the code to cause this to happen.

It's described in the documentation:

> The application's main() function must be called with C linkage, and should be declared like this:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus 
 extern "C" 
 #endif 
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
 { 
 }
```

so if you put the:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
```

immediately before the declaration of the main function, it should link correctly.

Comment: Oh, I was unable to find that bit of documentation. Thanks! I'll add that too, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a fix. I had to put this code in. Also, the answer above is good. Now I know why it happens too. Google did not find that document.

```
extern "C"
{
#include "common.h"
}
```